# Recovery mode starts with RW filesystem

Tags: boot, filesystem, data-recovery

I'm running Kubuntu 22.04 and I can't seem to get it to start with the root filesystem mounted as read-only. Looking at the kernel parameters for recovery mode, grub does pass ro, recovery, and a couple of other parameters I don't know to the kernel. However, if I go to the menu option to open a shell, the root partition is loaded RW. I've tried changing the recovery parameter to single which skips the menu and goes straight to a shell, but root is still mounted RW. I need to do something with the filesystem mounted RO but once it's RW, I can't change it as it's busy. It certainly doesn't seem ideal for a "recovery mode"...

Comment: You've not mention what Kubuntu system you're using, but why not just boot *live* media to perform your checks or whatever you want to do.

Comment: Well uname says I'm using #66-kubuntu, whatever that means. It's a complicated story, but I'm trying to copy files from an old raid array to a less old SATA drive and I have to set iommu=soft to access the raid array at all but due to a kernel bug, it corrupts the filesystem on my NVMe. Besides that, it's just kind of dumb to automatically mount it as RW when I go to single-user mode. If I want it in RW mode, I'll remount it myself.

Comment: The boot process reads data from your systems *file-system table* thus is a RW state exists there, it has a RW mount direction during the boot process.  As I suggested before, booting *live* media will bypass this.